# Snap to face not working

Tags: snapping

Snap to face isn't working. After enabling it, I selected the face I want to snap to and pressed enter (which I think is supposed to be done) and my snap to bar on the bottom looks like this.[image]

I want to move this vertex

[image]
but it ends up like this, even with snap on.

[image]
Help?

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: https://youtu.be/WwmdhqhD3aI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When set to *median* and *face* as target an objects median (center) will snap to a face.
This example shows how snapping works with different objects and snapping an edge of the same object.

[image]

When you use *closest* as snapping target then objects will snap to the top of the face.

---

Snapping doesn't work by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> by itself.

Using ***Face|Closest|Project individual elements on the surface of others*** you can achieve the following results but you should press <kbd>g</kbd> before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.8:

In Object Mode
In the Top Center of the 3D view is a Magnet Icon (Snapping) and a selection box for the settings.

Set the Settings to FACE, CLOSEST  and MOVE.

If you need the object to rotate (like to match a curved surface) turn on rotation as well.

This drove me INSANE because I kept snapping the center pivot of my object to the face, not the closest face.

Selecting CLOSEST fixes that.